# PHP - Google Image Grabber

Tags: php, regex

Basically I need this so I can grab a quick and simple 720p resolution image of whatever I searched for. It can be any image on the page but for relevance, the first image would be better to grab and save.

My current code:

```
<?php
$q = urlencode($_GET['q']);
$page = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=945&q=$q");
preg_match_all('~url?q=(.*)~', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
    echo "part 1: " . $val[1] . "\n";
    echo "part 2: " . $val[2] . "\n";
    echo "part 3: " . $val[3] . "\n";
    echo "part 4: " . $val[4] . "\n\n";
}
?>
```

Not sure why its not working, maybe my regex is off or something, but having just (*.) as the regex won't even output a single letter.

IMPORTANT:
It seems like this is the ouput im getting with file_get_contents:
http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Falls_(TV_series)&sa=U&ei=7U6SVd_tOMa2oQShrajgDg&ved=0CBYQ9QEwAA&usg=AFQjCNFtGgjaGTit0Q3291xaQHjOl8NmIA">

Comment: Are you trying to parse a query string of an URL? You should be using DOM to collect the links and then `parse_str` to get the value you need.

Comment: Nah I want it to be just a tiny old script you feel me? And basically I just did (.*) as regex and it showed me the ?thing= url im tryna get is /url?q=*Url Is Here*> I tried ~url?q=(.*)~ as regex but its not working what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should provide the sample input text you get and specify what text in in what context you want to obtain. Otherwise, we can just speculate as vks has already done. Let me try, too: [`images\/([^\/]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|bmp|gif))`](https://regex101.com/r/eU9zK4/1).

Comment: Images on google are 64base encoded ..., grabing them would require a bit more.

Comment: Yeah it didnt help at all :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, Thx guys rlly did me a favor with this one :D

Found it myself... -.-
Thats a good thing doe I guess :D

```
<?php
    $q = urlencode($_GET['q']);

    $url="https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=945&q=".$q;

    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);

    $expA=explode('href="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=',$result);
    $expB=explode('&',$expA[1]);
    $auth=$expB[0];
    echo $auth;
?>
```

Info:
Switched to cUrl as it bypasses this old timey looking bot protection page and shows the actual image url instead of an url like http://example.com/asdhrehfhJHfsjkh.skdhHJKf.

It gives you the link of the first image only which is great for just grabbing album art or something. (SOmething kinda like what im doing but to basically get screenshots).

Moved from regex to Explode() as I wasnt exactly searching for more then one item and I wasnt searching for soemthing extroardinarily needing regex so this explode works just fine.

Update:
This allowed to to remove anyhting after the .jpg etc:

```
if(preg_match('/(.*)(?:png|jpe?g|bmp|gif)/', $explodedresult, $match) !== false) {
    echo $match[0];
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';
}
```

This is useful becuase some urls will end up making it so that the text after the jpg will make the jpg file not load e.t.c for example this page:

```
http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/gravityfalls/images/1/16/Main_characters_of_Gravity_Falls.png/revision/latest%253Fcb%253D20140821174543
```

Comment: Just one thing to top the cherry, How could I get it to basically search and remove anything and everything after the resulted .jps, .png, .gif?